# Netsuite get record type by passing id SS 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How to get record type in createdfrom field for transaction records in SuiteScript 2.0

```
in suitescript 1.0 we use 
var createdfrom = nlapiGetFieldValue(createdfrom);
getRecordType(createdfrom);
```

This way i want to use in SS 2.0

Answer (score 3):

You could do a `search.lookupFields` on the record to get its `type`.

```
function getTransactionType(recordId) {
  var recTypeLookup = search.lookupFields({
                    type: search.Type.TRANSACTION,
                    id: recordId,
                    columns: 'type'
                });
    return recTypeLookup['type'][0].value;
}
```